# Position a 'last character' at the end of a text before \pagebreak (dito at the beginning @ next page)

Tags: page-breaking

Within a document, that spans several pages, I want to put specific text immediately at the end of the text on every page (same I want to do at the beginning of next page). I'm practically looking for the pendant to `\AtEndDocument{text}` on page level.

The pendant should do exactly that, but for every page, something like `\AtEndPage{here ends page \thepage}` and \AtBeginPage{here starts page \thepage}.

The **purpose** is as follows: It's a legal text and this is to omit that additional information (text) is added into free space before or after the original text. At the same time it's a document that is supposed to stay esthetic and this has to happen within the box of text which is holding the - let's say - text stream, not the footnote or so.

This shall happen

- within a `\begin{multicols}{2}` environment
- only when there is a pagebreak, so there will be no added text at the end of the document

This is what I would like and here I fixed it manually:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

        \textbf{Here will be a formal beginning, which indicates the legal beginning of the document, so no continuation-indicator is needed.}
        \lipsum[1-1]
        \footnote{This is a footnote that is outside the actual 'text stream'}
        \lipsum[1-1]
        % This is manual, I will not know, where the page will break.
        % The voulnerable part of the text is protected by this:
        \textbf{end of page \thepage}       % manual
        \newpage
        % %he voulnerable part of the text is protected by this:
        \textbf{start of page \thepage}     % manual
        \lipsum[1-3]
        \textbf{Here will be a formal end, which indicates the legal end of the document, so no continuation-indicator is needed.}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: May I ask what your specific use-case is? What's the reason for the text at the start and end of each page? Is it just a header and a footer? Please provide us with more information and an MWE with which we can play.

Comment: Take a look at the `continue` package.

Comment: the `continue` package puts the marker outside the actual text stream. But it is the right direction.